# Write equivalent of x == y using bit-level and logical operations?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, logical-operators

What is a C expression equivalent to x == y that only uses bit-level (|,~,^,&) and logical (&&,||,!) operations? It should return 1 when x and y are equal, 0 otherwise.

Comment: And your [partial] answer/solution is ..? Draw out the TTL for all the different cases. Don't forget that, for integers, `==` implies that *all* bits are a the same; now just work out the base case (with bitwise) for how to detect when *one* bit is the same and then apply it to all the bits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression `x==y` is equivalent to the [logical biconditional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional) expression `x<->y` (Evaluates to true iff x and y are equivalent). The biconditional is the inverse of the [exclusive or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) (Evaluates to true if x and y are not equivalent), so

`x==y` is equivalent to

**NOT ( x XOR y)**

which is

bit: `~(x^y)`

logical doesn't have **XOR**, so given that **x ⊕ y = (x ∨ y) ∧ !(x ∧ y)**

logical: `!((x || y) && !(x && y))`

*NOTE:* The above expressions are *logically* (a better word might be algebraicly?) equivalent. The bitwise comparison will of course just look at each bit. As @chux pointed out, this may give an unexpected result if 2 numbers are arithmetically equivalent, but have a different bit pattern. And the same issue arises in `C++` if you are comparing objects that have overridden the `==` operator. A gotcha for the logical version is that type coercion may occur if `x` and `y` are not the same variable type.

Comment: yoo......fyi it doesn't allow you to mark an answer within the first (idk how many) minutes. I just did it now anyways. @kpa6uk

Comment: "`x==y` is equivalent to `NOT ( x XOR y)`" works for unsigned integers but not _in general_ for `int` (nor FP).  Those types may have different bit patterns that have the same arithmetic value and this solution is doing a bit pattern compare.  +1 anyways as I'm sure this is sufficient for OP's need.